# Using Mercurial & Tortoisehg

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I am a long time user of Visual Source Safe, TFS or SVN at different times of my career. I want to switch over to Mercurial & TortoideHG.

I have downloaded TortoiseHG version 2.5 from 
[this page](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/index.html).

To start with I want to transfer a .net solution and the entire structure (folders/files etc) for that solution into the Mercurial Source Code control using TortoiseHG.

Questions

1. Can any one tell me in simple terms how to transfer the .net solution to source code control?
2. Do I use the Shell extension command to create a repository or the Tortoise Workbench?

I want to start using and learning the bare basics as I have mostly been using plugins from within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you need from the UI.
Start out from [Mercurial Webpage](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/).

Also good resources on getting started: [Re-educate yourself on version control](http://hginit.com/).